# ASP.NET MVC4 Building Custom Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to reuse an combo box control which occurs in various modules in our project. 
Combo box with Select, Yes and no items in it.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SampleList", new[] 
{
new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes",Value = "1" },
new SelectListItem() {Text = "No",Value = "2" }
},"Select")
```

What approach would be better?

To use Partial View or User Controls?

Also in certain forms they are repeated multiple time.

This is a questionnaire page.

Let me know if any further options are available as i am new to MVC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go for partial view, these type of thing we make and put it in a a folder named editor templates inside the shared folder. Also never heard of any thing like user controls in mvc

Comment: Hi Rex. But we see an optionw hile adding a new item MVC4 View User Control (ASPX) what would this do then?

Answer (score 2):

> To use Partial View or User Controls?

MVC doesn't have any notion of "user controls", partial views are pretty much the equivalent so they would be the most logical choice.

---

> In a form if were to use it in 4 different places then i will be able to call using `@Html.Partial` but how do i differentiate between the four controls?

Just make your partial view take in the ID field e.g.

```
@model string

@Html.DropDownList(Model, new[] 
{
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes",Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "No",Value = "2" }
}, new { id = "@Model" })
```

Which you could then call like

```
@Html.Partial("SelectList", "ddlOne");
@Html.Partial("SelectList", "ddlTwo");
@Html.Partial("SelectList", "ddlThree");
```

Comment: Thanks James.. In a form if were to use it in 4 different places then i will be able to call using @Html.Partial but how do i differentiate between the four controls? What i mean is typically when we create any controls we provide an ID against which we will be validating. How to go about it  in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks James. Let me try with those including the validation. :)

Comment: the ID's are not accessed by the jQuery. Here is a sample snippet from what you provided.
$('#cmb1').change(function () {
            alert('First Alert Message');
        }); cmb1 the id provided for the combo box is not detected. This change function never fires.

Comment: @GauthamNayak that isn't really much help... what does the HTML look like?

Comment: James. just take an example of a form which has questionnaire 
Are You? Yes/No
Are You? Yes/No etc. We will be having around 15 questions so i was trying to create an partial view so that we can reuse it rather than creating it every time.

Comment: @GauthamNayak no, I get that. What I meant was what does the generated HTML look like from the code I have provided you with? It should look like `<select id="ddlOne">...</select><select id="ddlTwo">...</select>` etc.

Comment: @GauthamNayak see update, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470329(v=vs.108).aspx) the first parameter is the `name` field not the ID, my mistake.